# Spring Boot Application- Ambiguous mapping Cannot map method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

i am creating a simple spring boot project when i run the project ran into the problem with **Spring Boot Ambiguous mapping**. Cannot map method. i have create two various controller those are student and course controller.i completly attached the error below.
i attached the full

```
**gub link here** https://github.com/raguram1986/SpringSecuritys
```

Full Error i attached below

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'studentController' method 
    com.example.studentmanagement.Controller.StudentController#saveStudent(Student)
    to {POST [/save]}: There is already 'courseController' bean method
    com.example.studentmanagement.Controller.CourseController#saveCourse(Course) mapped.
```

**Controller**

```
@Controller
public class StudentController {
    
        @Autowired
        private StudentService service;

        @GetMapping("/Student")
        public String viewHomePage(Model model) {
            List<Student> liststudent = service.listAll();
            // model.addAttribute("liststudent", liststudent);
            System.out.print("Get / "); 
            return "Student";
        }

        @GetMapping("/addStudent")
        public String add(Model model) {
            List<Student> liststudent = service.listAll();
            model.addAttribute("liststudent", liststudent);
            model.addAttribute("student", new Student());
            return "addstudent";
        }
        

        @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String saveStudent(@ModelAttribute("student") Student std) {
            service.save(std);
            return "Student";
        }

        @RequestMapping("/edit/{id}")
        public ModelAndView showEditStudentPage(@PathVariable(name = "id") int id) {
            ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("addstudent");
            Student std = service.get(id);
            mav.addObject("student", std);
            return mav;
            
        }
        @RequestMapping("/delete/{id}")
        public String deleteStudentPage(@PathVariable(name = "id") int id) {
            service.delete(id);
            return "Student";
        }
```

**Student**

```
@Entity
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String stname;
    private String course;
    private int fee;
    
    
    public Student() {
    }

    
    public Student(Long id, String stname, String course, int fee) {
    
        this.id = id;
        this.stname = stname;
        this.course = course;
        this.fee = fee;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getStname() {
        return stname;
    }
    public void setStname(String stname) {
        this.stname = stname;
    }
    public String getCourse() {
        return course;
    }
    public void setCourse(String course) {
        this.course = course;
    }
    public int getFee() {
        return fee;
    }
    public void setFee(int fee) {
        this.fee = fee;
    }
```

**StudentRepository**

```
@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Long>{    
}
```

**Service**

```
@Service
public class StudentService 
{
    @Autowired
    private StudentRepository repo;
    
    public List<Student> listAll() {
        return repo.findAll();
    }
     
    public void save(Student std) {
        repo.save(std);
    }
     
    public Student get(long id) {
        return repo.findById(id).get();
    }
     
    public void delete(long id) {
        repo.deleteById(id);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `StudentController` you have the endpoint `/save`

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveStudent(@ModelAttribute("student") Student std) {
    service.save(std);
    return "Student";
}
```

But you haven't included the `CourseController` class in your question, which is mentioned in the error.

If you have defined an endpoint `/save` in that `CourseController`, then you have to rename it. Otherwise, when you invoke `/save` which controller needs to be invoked cannot be determined.

Comment: i did the way as you said but no error. page blank.i need to display the index page i added the links course and student links. i attached on git hub i added the link above

Answer (score 0):

Add `@RequestMapping` above `StudentController` as below

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/students")
public class StudentController {
    ...
}
```

You are getting exception because there is already a mapping defined for path

```
/save
```

without being any controller mapping, so the first with root mapping is considered, but the next time it encounters same mapping it is already registered hence it is complaining. For clarity i'd suggest to add `@RequestMapping` to CourseController as well.

So now your course controller also becomes:

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/courses")
public class CourseController {
    ...
}
```

Comment: i did the way as you said but no error. page blank.i need to display the index page i added the links course and student links. i attached on git hub i added the link above

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to always add a request mapping at class level as well, like in your case, add a mapping like "/students" for SutdentController and "/course" for CourseController itself and then all other methods will be under that i.e. "/student/save" and then you will not face this issue anymore.

Comment: i did the way as you said but no error. page blank.i need to display the index page i added the links course and student links. i attached on git hub i added the link above